# Python-Indexing- I do not understand how this bit of code is working

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I do not understand is how indexing a string s = "azcbobobegghakl" would correctly give me the answer 'beggh' if I was looking for the longest substring in alphabetical order. How does this code tell the computer that 'beggh' is in alphabetical order? I thought indexing just gave each letter in the string a number that increased by one until the string ended? I tweaked the code a bit and it worked, but I do not actually understand how the code works in the first place.

```
s = "azcbobobegghakl"
longest = s[0]
current = s[0]
for c in s[1:]:
    if c >= current[-1]:
        current += c
    else:
        if len(current) > len(longest):
            longest = current
        current = c
print "Longest substring in alphabetical order is:", longest
```

Comment: Because I'm insane, this seems like a fun one to one-line with equivalent big-O (it's too easy if you can use naive solutions): `from itertools import chain, groupby`, `from operator import itemgetter, le`, define `s`, then the one-liner is: `longest = max((''.join(chain(next(g), map(itemgetter(1), g))) for is_ordered, g in groupby(zip(chain(('',), s[:-1]), s), key=lambda p: le(*p)) if is_ordered), key=len)`. This is not really intended to be _helpful_, just showing off what terrible/awesome things you can do with `itertools` and `operator`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`>=` compares two characters by their lexicographical order; the expression

```
if c >= current[-1]:
```

tests if `c` (a single character), is the same or is 'greater' than `current[-1]` (another single character. Strings are ordered lexicographically by their codepoint value; `a` is smaller than `b` because the character `a` comes before `b` in the Unicode standard:

```
>>> 'a' > 'b'
False
>>> 'a' < 'b'
True
```

As such, characters are only added to `current` if they come 'later' in the alphabet than the last character of `current`. If they do not, then the sequence so far is tested for length, and a *new* substring is started from `c`.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `c >= current[-1]` lexicographically compares each character with its predecessor in the string. More simply:

```
>>> 'a' >= 'a'
True
>>> 'b' >= 'a'
True
>>> 'b' >= 'c'
False
>>> 'z' >= 'a'
True
```

So all the code is doing is to accumulate runs of characters that have each character `>=` the last one, and to keep the longest one seen.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "azcbobobegghakl"

# initialize vars to first letter in string
longest = s[0]
current = s[0]

# start iterating through rest of string
for c in s[1:]:

    # c is the letter of current iteration and current[-1]
    # is the last letter of the current string. Every character 
    # has an ASCII value so this is checking the character's 
    # numerical values to see if they are in alphabetical order (a<b<c etc.)
    if c >= current[-1]:

        # so if c is bigger than current[-1] (meaning it comes
        # after in the alphabet, then we want to add it to current
        current += c
    else:
        # if c was smaller then we want to check if the alphabetic
        # string we just read is longer than the previous longest
        if len(current) > len(longest):
            longest = current

        # start the current string over beginning with the letter in c
        current = c
print "Longest substring in alphabetical order is:", longest
```

Comment: So python does this automatically, without having to call any functions up? What initializes(?) the code assigning the ASCII value and comparing them?

Comment: ASCII stands for American Standard Code for Information Interchange and they decided what each characters value is around 50ish years ago. You can read about ASCII here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII. It's the job of the OS and the compiler to convert the bit values into their respective letters. Take a look here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/273334/how-are-ascii-code-associations-actually-stored-and-retrieved